# Task was destroyed but it is pending when trying to run a aiohttp server using HTTPS

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Trying to figure out how to make HTTPS work with [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web.html) server but I keep getting the error below when I try to make a request to a route while using `ssl_context`.

> Task was destroyed but it is pending!

If I remove `ssl_context` from `web.run_app` the server works fine but I can not access the server via HTTPS. Not sure if I am not using `ssl_context` the right way? Any insight would be greatly appreciated. My server sample is below:

```
import json
import asyncio

from aiohttp import web
from aiomysql import create_pool
from aiomysql import DictCursor

host = 'localhost'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
db = 'db'

routes = web.RouteTableDef()
headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
}
async def fetch_data(table):
    async with create_pool(host=host,port=3306,user=user,password=password,db=db) as pool:
        async with pool.get() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor(DictCursor) as cur:
                sql = "SELECT id FROM `{}`"
                sql = sql.format(table)
                await cur.execute(sql)
                dataset = await cur.fetchall()
                return dataset

@routes.get('/hello')
async def hello(request):
    dataset = await fetch_data('my_table')
    return web.json_response(dataset, headers=headers)

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes(routes)
web.run_app(app, port=9090, ssl_context='https')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create SSL context (e.g. with method `ssl.create_default_context()`) and then supply certificate to it (can be self-signed).

To create self-signed certificate, use this command (just leave all questions with default values):

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.crt
```

Then, in your script create ssl context with this certificate:

```
import ssl

sc = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
sc.load_cert_chain('selfsigned.crt', 'selfsigned.key')
```

...and then supply it to your `web.run_app()`:

```
web.run_app(app, port=9090, ssl_context=sc)
```

Running the server and navigating to your page through https should work now, but, of course you need to confirm in browser that the certificate is correct.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you! Now would I be able to use the SSL that is already installed for the domain that is running the server? Or dose it have to be a self-signed cert? Because when I try to request the route I get "Your connection is not private" but I assume that is because it is self-signed?

Comment: @antfuentes87 Yes, if you have own certificate (from example Let's encrypt), you can use it in your program. With self-signed certificate you'll always get the browser warning message. I would recommend running the Python aiohttp app in http mode behind some proxy (nginx for example, that will handle SSL for you).

Comment: Well at the moment (I can look into switching over to nginx) I am running on WHM/cPanel (Apache). I am running the server from one of the cpanel accounts which has a SSL installed already. Where would the `.crt` and `.key`. files be located? I assume I would I would put the file paths for those two files in `sc.load_cert_chain('selfsigned.crt', 'selfsigned.key')` in order to use the domains SSL?

Comment: @antfuentes87 You need to ask your service provider where the certificates are loaded. You can also make proxy with Apache server - but that depends on service provider too.

Comment: I was able to find them myself and it worked! That is awesome! Thank you very much. I was messing around with the `create_default_context` but did not realize you could just load a pre-existing SSL. Once again thank you!